# React set audio.ended listener

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-audio

As I've researched on some answers here, a nice way to add audio in React app is the following:

```
import music from '~assets'

class Audio extends Component {
  state = {...}
  audio = new Audio(music)
  ...
  this.audio.play()
  this.audio.pause()
  ...
}
```

After implementing that I realized that I'm unable to set it to auto-replay unless paused. **Is there a way to do so with current setup without switching to explicitly creating `<audio />` tag?**

PS. As I see it, the main problem is that I can't find a way to attach a `onended` listener or correct place to check for `this.audio.ended`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is much easier than I could've expected.

In the function that I use to invoke `this.audio.play()` I added `loop` property to audio

```
play = () => {
if (this.audio === null) {
  this.audio = new Audio(music);
}
this.audio.loop = true; //this one
this.setState({ play: true, pause: false });
this.audio.play();
};
```